# jquery ajax - passing checkbox values with Joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla

I've got an html table with a number of checkboxes :

```
<table id="webcam-table" class="pretty">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Camera Name</th>
        <th>Date Created</th>
        <th>Video Size</th>
        <th>Video Length</th>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxselectall" title="Select All" />
        <button type="submit" class="deletebutton" name="delete_video" title="Delete the selected videos">Delete</button></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form name="myform" action="">
        <tr >
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo $this->result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo setlocalTime($this->result_videos[$i]["video_datetime"]); ?> 
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo ByteSize($this->result_videos[$i]["video_size"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');">
                        <?php echo strTime($this->result_videos[$i]["video_length"]); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $this->result_videos[$i]["video_name"]; ?>" title="Mark this video for deletion"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

There is a bunch of code I'm omitting that is php code to build the table. Notice the input type checkbox value returns the name of the video. This is necessary to delete the video. My jquery code to process the value of each video:

```
jQuery(".deletebutton").on("click", function() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete the selected videos?"))
    {
        var values = [jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get()];
        alert(values);
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&videonames=+values+&format=raw',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                $this.closest("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The user can select one or more checkboxes and hit the delete button. This should return the values of the checkboxes (all the video names), they get deleted and I remove the rows in the table.

Here's the problem. I'm using Joomla component development so I pass the values in the url. The names of the videos are way too long to do this. Someone can select up to 100 video names which makes the url string way too long. Can anyone suggest an alternative?

**EDIT:** I changed this to an array based on @Dasun feedback. See above for `values`. If I test this value with:

```
alert(values);
```

I get an output that looks like: `blah.mp4,foo.mp4,bar.mp4`. Which I expect. But each video name is on the query string which I don't want. Either I'm not creating the array correctly or I don't understand how you only pass the array object and not the entire contents of the array on the query string.

Comment: Deleting a video using a simple query string that we can easily find in the source code... Hope there is a check for the current user/owner of the video...

Comment: @JohnJohnGa of course, on the server side. Plus this is all behind user login and the video name is obfuscated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe if you request is a POST in your php code you wil be looking for $_POST['videonames']
then you shuld pass them as the data parameter of the request.

also to pass it trought GET it shuld look like

```
   &videonames[0]=values[0]&videonames[1]=values[1]
```

maybe this code will work:

```
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&format=raw',
     data: { 'videonames': values},
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
      alert('done');
     },
     error : function() {
      alert('error');
     } 
     });
```

Comment: This was it! Well mostly...I passed it in as an array. So I removed `dataType: json`. The key here was using `data: {videonames:values}` and then I access it with `JRequest::getVar('videonames', 0, 'post', 'array');` on the php side. Sweet, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right below should help you out.

Using Joomla notation retrieve the data.

```
$array_json = JRequest::getVar('data', 0, '');
```

Updated answer as requested.

You can use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to transfer all your data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'index.php?option=com_recordings&task=deletevideos&videonames=+values+&format=raw',
  data: values,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(result) {
   alert('done');
  },
  error : function() {
   alert('error');
  } 
  });
```

At the PHP level retrieve them as shown above(getVar). Then decode the data which are sent via AJAX. Use `json_decode` which will decodes a JSON string. [Read more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

EG :

```
$x = json_decode($array_json);
print_r($x);
```

If you have any issues let me know.

Comment: Not sure I understand, wouldn't the names of the videos still be in the POST url even if it is stored in an array? That is what I'm trying to avoid, it is too long.

Comment: Still missing something. I've updated my post. Perhaps I'm creating the array incorrectly?

Comment: I would remove "values" from the url would I not? I believe you are suggesting I change my array to JSON format instead?

Comment: you don't have to use it in the URL. Yes remove it. AJAX call will transfer all the data for you

Comment: json format has me confused I put a simple example: `var JSONObject= {
     "name":"John Johnson",
     "street":"Oslo West 555"};` and put `data:JSONObject` in ajax call but I still get json parse error. Any ideas?

Comment: It validates fine. I'm just taking a simple w3fools example.

Comment: create your array and pass it using the ajax request not the sample

Comment: that's the first thing I tried. It gives me a json parse error as well. That's why I tried some simple json sample to verify it wasn't my array.

Comment: Doesn't look like a json problem, I think I've sorted that out. But `$array_json` or `$x` are always empty (or 0 because of the default value).